# AVPlayer not playing on iOS 9

Tags: ios, iphone, streaming, avplayer

I'm trying to build a audio streaming app, like a radio. This is the URL of the stream: `http://radio.livesh.com.br:8068/`

This is basically how I do:

```
player = AVPlayer()
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem( URL:NSURL(string:streamURL)! )
player = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
player.rate = 1.0;
player.play()
```

The `player` var is stored so it does keep playing and is not being deinit'ed. In an iPhone 5S with iOS 8 it works and I can hear the sounds. In an iPhone 6 with iOS 9 it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see any messages in the console or device log?

Comment: There is no errors on console

Comment: Look in the device log.

Comment: Device logs shows nothing. It is not crashing. Just wont play sounds

Answer (score 3):

could be the ATS (app transport security) which enforces usage of https instead of http

you can either serve your content over https or create an exception on the info.plist file as such:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>radio.livesh.com.br</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: No, I have disabled ATS for all domains (while in development)